# Infinite straight wires Vector potential

Tags: electromagnetism

I have this question to write down the vector potentials for four straight wires parallel to the $z$-axis cross the $xy$-plane
at the vertices of a square: $(a, a), (a, −a), (−a, a)$ and
$(−a, −a)$. The wires through points $(a, a)$ and $(−a, −a)$
carry current $I$ in the positive $z$-direction; the wires
through $(a, −a)$ and $(−a, a)$ carry current $I$ in the negative
$z$-direction.

I have already worked out the formula for the vector potential ($A(x,y)$)
which is:

$A(x,y)=-\frac{\mu_0k}{4\pi}I\ln(x^2+y^2)$

But I'm struggling to see how to write down the vector potential for this case.

Is this the answer?

$A(x,y)=-\frac{\mu_0k}{4\pi}I\ln((x-a)^2+(y-a)^2+(x-a)^2+(y+a)^2+(x+a)^2+(y-a)^2+(x+a)^2+(y+a)^2)$

Comment: Could you elaborate more? You've worked out a formula for the vector potential, but you've said you're struggling to see how to write down the vector potential for this case.

Comment: I suppose what I am struggling with the fact that their is four currents, and I don't know whether I can add them or whatever.

Comment: Is this the answer?

$A(x,y)=-\frac{\mu_0k}{4\pi}I\ln((x-a)^2+(y-a)^2+(x-a)^2+(y+a)^2+(x+a)^2+(y-a)^2+(x+a)^2+(y+a)^2)$